# How to copy all the info from clipboard via AppleScript

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

Here is the thing:
 I'm using AppleScript in Automator to get the clipboard value, and of course it works, but when I want to get multiple separated value, it always returns me only one value on the top。
 Here is the step:

1. In Automator, import multiple "Get Value of Variable"  actions, and
   in these actions, I will set multiple values, all of these values
   are e-mail format
2. Import an action named “Ask For Confirmation”, without this action,
   I can’t pass multiple values to the next action “Choose from list”(I
   don’t know why, but it works)
3. Import an action named “Choose from list” to let users choose the
   e-mail values I’ve pre-set in this Automator application
4. Import another action named “Set Value of Variable” to get the
   values users have chosen
5. Import an action named ”Copy to Clipboard” to copy these values to
   clipboard
6. Import an action named “Run AppleScript” and here is my code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    --get the clipboard info
    set Storage to get the clipboard
    display dialog Storage
    return input
end run
```

[image: Here is the whole actions picture]

I've tried to copy some text_1, text_2 ... manually(command+c, command+v) and then run my AppleScript only, and it turns out the result what I really want like this:
[image: AppleScript Result]

Here is my Script Editor code:
[image: Here is my Script Editor code:]

I have to say, due to some limitation I can only use Automator and AppleScript，so is there any solution or suggestion?
Here is the "Get Value of Variable" picture
[Get Value of Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFOw5.png)

Comment: Show how you are setting `Get Value of Variable` and how they are choosing them.

Comment: add "Get Value of Variable" and then set the varible name as "testforstackoverflowanswer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Possible Explanation:

I believe this is a bug in either the *Automator* **`Copy To Clipbard`** action or AppleScript.  *Automator* actions are often written in Objective-C, and it has some data types that AppleScript doesn't.  It looks like the *Automator* action copies an **array** to the clipboard, which is something you can do with Objective-C, but not with AppleScript.

My feeling is that AppleScript is the entity at fault here, as the action is doing what it is meant to, and within the *Automator* context, it wouldn't pose a problem keeping the clipboard's data as an array type.  AppleScript likely hasn't catered for this in its implementation of clipboard data handling, and does a poor job of coercing the array or list into plain text, which—as you stated—only contains the first element of the array.

### Solutions:

### 1. Use a `do shell script` command

Instead of:

```
set Storage to get the clipboard
```

try:

```
set Storage to do shell script "pbpaste"
```

### 2. Use AppleScriptObjC

Since the *Automator* action is probably written in ObjC, it's reasonable to assume that using AppleScriptObjC will give us access to the necessary data types.

Replace your entire AppleScript with this:

```
    use framework "Foundation"
    use scripting additions

    set Storage to (current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard's ¬
        stringForType:(current application's NSPasteboardTypeString)) ¬
        as text

    display alert Storage
```

### 3. Access the data through the `input` variable

The **`Run AppleScript`** action in *Automator* takes the result of the previous action and stores it in the variable attached to the `on run {input, parameters}` handler, namely `input` (you can ignore `parameters`).

Currently, your workflow actually sends the contents of the clipboard (the output of the **`Copy To Clipboard`** action) directly to the `input` variable of your AppleScript.

Therefore, you can replace the entire AppleScript with this:

```
    on run {input, parameters}

        set the text item delimiters to linefeed
        set Storage to the input as text

        display dialog Storage

    end run
```

---

Any one of these solutions should work, so just choose your preferred method.  **Number #3** probably makes most sense in your current set up, and is the simplest.

Comment: Hello friend, I have to say, you really hit the target, that's what I want, thank you

Comment: @JasonWang: Please click the checkmark on the upper of this answer (“accept”). This indicates that the answer solved your issue and rewards the person who helped you by giving them reputation.

Comment: Thanks again, I’ve clicked it

Comment: This info is quite helpful/useful, but I'm not sure it technically solves the "copy *all* the info from clipboard" part of the problem. Case in point, if I copy a few files to the clipboard in Finder, and try any of the solutions mentioned, and then restore the clipboard from whatever variable is being used, when I try to paste the copied files in Finder, at worst nothing happens (clipboard core flavor is changed to plain text), and at best, I might be able to paste only one of the files copied to the clipboard.

Comment: @MaxWell Did you examine these solutions to try and understand what they were doing before concluding they didn't do what you wanted ? Bear in mind, this was solving a problem different to yours (and it's five years old). Notably, you'll see that every solution intentionally takes that which was copied to the clipboard and coerces it into `text`. So I believe you've actually just confirmed this solution still functions correctly. However, you've failed to adapt it properly to suit your use-case. Would you like help with doing this ?